# Spring, JPA: How to query for Entities under another Entity with a many-to-many relationship bridge table setup

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jpa, jpql

I'm fairly new to Spring. I'm trying to query all the donations under one donor with this ERD:

Donor |----* Agreement *----| Donations (A many-to-many relationship that uses a bridge table)

Here's my code:

Donor.java

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Donor extends Auditable implements Comparable<Donor>{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank(message = "Cannot have an empty account number field.")
    private String accountNumber;
    private String accountName;
    private String salutation;
    private String donorName;
    private String cellphoneNumber;
    private String emailAddress;
    private String companyTIN;
    private String phone1;
    private String phone2;
    private String faxNumber;
    private String address1;
    private String address2;
    private String address3;
    private String address4;
    private String address5;
    private String companyAddress;
    private LocalDate birthDate;
    private String notes;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "donor")
    List<MOA> moaList = new ArrayList<>();
    ...
}
```

Donation.java

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Donation extends Auditable implements Comparable<Donation> {
   
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @NotBlank(message = "Cannot have an empty account number field.")
    private String accountNumber;
    private String accountName;
    private String orNumber;
    private String date;
    private Double amount;
    private String notes;
    private String needCertificate;
    private String purposeOfDonation;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "donation")
    List<MOA> moaList = new ArrayList<>();
    ...
}
```

MOA.java (Agreement)

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MOA extends Auditable{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "donor_id")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("moaList")
    private Donor donor;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "donation_id")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("moaList")
    private Donation donation;

    private String name;
    private String donorAccountNumber;
    private Long foreignDonationId;
    private LocalDate dateSigned;
}
```

In my DonorRepository I'm trying to make this query which I expected would give me what I want:

```
public interface DonorRepository extends JpaRepository<Donor, Long> {
    ...
    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM donor WHERE account_number = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Donation> findDonorsDonations(String accountNumber);
    ...
```

This gives me an error

> Failed to convert from type [java.lang.Object[]] to type [com.package.server.domain.Donation] for value '{1, admin, 2021-04-01 10:29:53.0, admin, 2021-04-01 10:29:53.0, School, 123456, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, John Doe, null, null, null, null, null, Mr.}'; nested exception is org

Comment: You are querying from donor but the method returns `Donation`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use specification api and SpecificationExecutor.

You have to Join Donation with MAO(MAO with Donor) then query for donations of a particular Donor.